# Is it possible to send NFC APDU commands with iOS12

Tags: ios, nfc, ios12

It was rumored that with iOS12 Apple would free the access to the NFC reader, allowing it to be used for pourposes other then just NFC Tag reading.
Apparently there was no mention at the keynote. So is it confirmed or refuted?

Comment: There is nothing in the beta SDK http://codeworkshop.net/objc-diff/sdkdiffs/ios/12.0/CoreNFC.html

Comment: They are definitely opening it up, though. They made mention of several college campuses using the new NFC capabilities to let your phone do everything your Student ID can do, they also used the example of a Hotel's app being able to unlock your room. But I haven't been able to find any specific examples or any code on how to do it yet.

Comment: @vtcajones apparently this is limited in functionalities and you need to get a certificate from Apple to do it.

Comment: The only things I see is that they opened it up for background scanning (with restrictions). Don't see anything in the api to issue APDU commands.